# Implement hreflang with multiple regions same language and page

Tags: seo, local-seo, seo-audit, negative-seo, localization

My search results seem to not be correctly localized since adding a 'Europe' /eu/ page.

My header now looks like this (taken from EU page https://example.com/eu/features/).

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="https://example.com/us/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="https://example.com/au/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ie" href="https://example.com/ie/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-fr" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-es" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-de" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-it" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-pt" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-nl" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-be" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ch" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-at" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gr" href="https://example.com/eu/features/">
```

Anything incorrect with this implementation?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Since watching this video https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en It seems to be correct, interested to hear others thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your `hreflang` are unneeded, maybe because you are confusing languages and localizations.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646.html#section-2.2.4 :

> Region subtags are used to indicate linguistic variations associated
> with or appropriate to a specific country, territory, or region.
> Typically, a region subtag is used to indicate variations such as
> regional dialects or usage, or region-specific spelling conventions.

As such, what sense do you have for `en-fr`, `en-be`, `en-gr`, etc.?
English, as spoken in France, Belgium or Greece, is still English. There is no specific dialect there, nor spelling conventions. You can debate if it is the `en-us` or `en-gb` variants, or if it is broken English or business English, but clearly `en-fr` and others are not needed...

Further, see [section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646.html#section-4.1):

> A subtag SHOULD only be used when it adds useful distinguishing
> information to the tag.  Extraneous subtags interfere with the
> meaning, understanding, and processing of language tags.

The fact that most of your tags refer to only one URL, which is also the one for `en-gb` again shows that there are many unneeded values.

These values depict languages, potentially if dialects exist the way they are spoken in specific places on the map, but these values do not depict localization. So `en-fr` does not mean "the English page content for people living in France".

You can go to https://r12a.github.io/app-subtags/ to check valid language tags, but this is mostly a syntax check. If you put `en-fr` (or even `en-gb` in fact) you get this warning:

> Check that the region subtag GB contributes information needed to
> distinguish this language tag from another one, otherwise leave it
> out.

Comment: They have different pricing custom to those regions, what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: The correct way, I do not know/judge, but in many websites you have dropdowns, or account settings, to choose the localization/language/currency to use. Or you try to use geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead, where the default is as the bottom of the list, i can't see any obvous errors but there may be other factors, covered in this article.

Do you need to use both the following lines of code:


I would remove the second line as its not needed as you have already specified the default page.

Also You will need to ensure that GSC (google Search Console) is setup properly for each property added and set the correct region or you will be sending conflicting signals to Google about what property targets which region.

Also ensure that you are not redirecting users based on IP address as this can mess up everything.

You can also use this free [hreflang testing tool](https://technicalseo.com/tools/hreflang/) to check implementation on a specific page, which may highlight any errors. [This tool](https://app.hreflang.org) will test the code itself but needs actual URLs rather than exampe.com.